# Java applet throwing Exception In Initializer Error

Tags: java, html, eclipse, applet

I have the following code in a HTML file

```
<html>
<title>Applet Test</title>
<body>
<applet
archive = "TheSlot.jar"
code = "slotMachine/The_Main.class" 
width = "300" 
height = "300">
</applet>
</body>
</html>
```

But whenever I try to run it, the java loading circle appears but it never loads, instead throwing a `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`

Does anyone have a solution for this? My The_Main class extends Applet and it runs in Eclipse and on its own as a jar file on my desktop. It has multiple class files so that puts me in the position of needing the jar file...

Comment: We cannot help if we don't see any code and stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

When you run this it will throw the same exception

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
```

check you code too that you have initilize something that cause this error as in below example this happans in this line

```
num[34]=2;
```

and it is in static initializer check that too.

```
class EX
{
static
{
int num[]= {34};
num[34]=2;
  }
 static void display()
 {
 System.out.println("this is display");
 }
 }

class exception1
{

public static void main(String args[])
{
EX.display();
System.out.println("om namah sivaya");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this thread is a littl bit old:
I stumbled about this on one of my own applets. They worked on different machines, but on one i got this exception.
My solution was to fix the deploment.properties file.
Maybe this helps someone sometimes.

Comment: What exactly did you fix in that file?